# Jenkins ping thread freezing other threads?

Tags: java, jenkins, ping

**Question**: Has someone seen behavior like this? Can this even possibly mean what it looks to be meaning? I.e. when the ping is sent everything stops breathing until pong comes back: pages load longer/stop loading and build console log is not retrieved 'continuously' until pong.

Here's the ping thread from thread dump:

`Ping thread for channel hudson.remoting.Channel@32a6cf5b:<host>
"Ping thread for channel hudson.remoting.Channel@32a6cf5b:<host>" Id=108 Group=main TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.PingThread.run(PingThread.java:91)`

The rest of thread dump (specifically jobs) looks more or less like this:

`Executor #6 for <host> : executing <job> #<build_number> / waiting for hudson.remoting.Channel@32a6cf5b:<host>`
`"Executor #6 for eselivm2v759l : executing mct_up_check #2004 / waiting for hudson.remoting.Channel@32a6cf5b:<host>" Id=625627 Group=main TIMED_WAITING on hudson.remoting.UserRequest@7654c0aa
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on hudson.remoting.UserRequest@7654c0aa
    at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:146)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:751)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:173)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56.join(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$ProcImpl.join(Launcher.java:979)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.join(CommandInterpreter.java:137)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:97)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:533)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1745)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)`